# Langchain: ChromaDB: Not able to retrive large numbers of PDF files vector database from Chroma persistence directory

Tags: similarity, langchain, chromadb

My programme is chatting with PDF files in a directory. Surprisingly the code works if there 5 PDF files in directory of 1 page each. But it doesn't work when there are 1000 files of 1 page each. It seems Chroma vectordb is not getting initialized when dealing with large number of files. However, there is no. error code.

**code:**

```
MD5hash_pdf_persits_dir = hashlib.md5(pdf_folder_path.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
if os.path.exists(MD5hash_pdf_persits_dir):
    vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=MD5hash_pdf_persits_dir,
                         embedding_function=HuggingFaceEmbeddings())
else:
    pdf_loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(pdf_folder_path)
    pdf_docs = pdf_loader.load()
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
    all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(pdf_docs)
    vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=all_splits,
                                        embedding=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(),
                                        persist_directory=MD5hash_pdf_persits_dir)
    vectordb.persist()
    vectordb = None
    vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=MD5hash_pdf_persits_dir,
                         embedding_function=HuggingFaceEmbeddings())
```

```
docs = vectordb.similarity_search(query=query, k=3)
chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff")
response = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)
```

Any pointers from experts will help.

same code works fine for small directory (5 files) but  returns no docs when vectordb of 1000 files is loaded. Further, vectordb director doesn't consist

data_level0.bin header.bin      length.bin      link_lists.bin

files when it fails.

Comment: This code is part of the streamlit app. It seems database is not initialized due to context switching. Any pointer to root cause and fix will help.

Comment: Experts any pointers? vectordb director doesn't consist

data_level0.bin header.bin length.bin link_lists.bin

Answer (score 0):

This is because here

`text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)`

If you fit a large number of pdf files, you must increase chunk_size or chunk_overlap or both of them up.

This is my process for loading all file txt, it sames the pdf:

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader, DirectoryLoader

loader=DirectoryLoader(path='./',
                       glob='./*.txt',
                       loader_cls=TextLoader)

documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents=documents)

persist_directory = 'db'

embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts,
                                 embedding=embedding,
                                 persist_directory=persist_directory)

vectordb.persist()
```

Comment: NO, it seems with large number of files, thread is getting swiched before completion and main thread running again, finding db and trying to initialize vectordb from it and failing